# What alternatives are there for C++ operator overloading syntax?

Tags: syntax, operators, operator-overloading

I noticed C++ has operator overloading syntax with just the operator names:

```
T& operator +(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
    return /* ... */;
}
```

However, there are 2 distinct operators that are both `++` and `--`. One being a suffix and one being a prefix. C++ syntax has no way to distinguish them with the syntax, so instead one of them uses an unused `int` parameter. But this seems ungraceful.

What would be a good alternative syntax for operator overloading that could unambiguously distinguish unary `+` with binary `+` and also distinguish `++x` from `x++` without hacks such as unused parameters?

Comment: The _advantage_ of the C++ style syntax is not having to remember made-up names for all the operators (like `__add__` in Python for example), although unfortunately you do end up with some cases like mentioned in this question.

Comment: The evil answer would be `T &operator(T &t)++;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Rust-style traits

In Rust, operator overloading is implemented using core traits built into the language, which allow the operators to be named, without conflicting with methods which have the same name (e.g., you may want `x.add()` to be different from the `+` overload, maybe if `x` is a set).

This would look something like:

```
impl core::ops::Add for T {
    fn add(...) -> T { ... }
}
```

The advantage of this is that, unless the `core::ops::Add` trait is `use`d in a file, this `add` method will not be accessable. This allows other `add` functions to be implemented on `T` without conflict.

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4902aa8acad0ad9673a2aba3e17f062e)

Answer (score 12):

## Using names instead

To rectify this problem, you can use names instead of symbols for the names of operator functions. For example, take a look at Kotlin:

```kotlin
operator fun inc(): X {
    // ++a/a++
}
operator fun plus(other: Y): Z {
    // a + b
}
```

Comment: Python also takes this approach. For example, `+` is implemented by `__add__` and `__radd__` (a cooperative protocol is used to check the LHS and RHS types for an implementation, and `+=` can be specialized using `__iadd__` (although it does not perform the actual assignment).

Comment: And while Python doesn't have pre- or post-increment operators, if it did I would expect them to have distinct dunder methods, e.g. `__preinc__` and `__postinc__`.

Answer (score 9):

Prefix the operator with its syntactic type. Raku allows the user to define custom operators with virtually any string of symbols (or letters, in fact) as names. The ambiguity is resolved by an explicit declaration at function site of which form of syntax the operator takes.

```
# Prefix ++
sub prefix:<++>($arg) {
  ...
}

# Postfix ++
sub postfix:<++>($arg) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The arguments could be placed next to the operator in relation to their usage, as opposed to in a list afterwards:

```
(T) ++(T) {
    // Prefix
}

(T) (T)++ {
    // Suffix 
}

(T) +(T) {
    // Unary
}

(T) (T)+(T) {
    // Binary
}
```

The types would likely have to be parenthesized to avoid ambiguous syntax.

Comment: I really like this. Agda does something similar, where the name of a function has underscores in the places that it should expect arguments, so `_++` is the postfix function's name and `++_` is the prefix one. You can also go a little bit crazy: `_≡⟨_⟩_` is a real function from the Agda stdlib that is quite commonly used.

Comment: "The types would likely have to be parenthesized to avoid ambiguous syntax." I think this is likely only an issue for languages with relatively expressive type systems. I can see it causing a problem if e.g. `<>` are used to indicate type parametrization.

Answer (score 8):

## UpValues in Mathematica

Mathematica (the Wolfram Language) is based on pattern matching and term rewriting. Functions are defined as rules. For example, when you define a function like this:

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

It defines a rule that says "when you see `f[x_]`, replace it with `x^2`". This rule is associated with the symbol `f`, and is called a "downvalue" of `f`.

Mathematica also has "upvalues", where the rule is associated with a symbol in the function's arguments instead of the function's name. For example, if you define:

```
f[x] ^:= x^2
```

Then the rule is associated with the symbol `x`, and is called an "upvalue" of `x`.

Operators in Mathematica are just syntactic sugar for built-in functions. For example, `a + b` is equivalent to `Plus[a, b]`. Downvalues for built-in functions are protected, so you can't redefine `Plus` directly. However, you can define upvalues for your own symbols.

For example, if you want to define your own complex number type, you can define a symbol `Comp`, and then define addition and multiplication for it:

```
Comp[a_, b_] + Comp[c_, d_] ^:= Comp[a + c, b + d]
Comp[a_, b_] * Comp[c_, d_] ^:= Comp[a c - b d, a d + b c]
```

These rules are associated with the symbol `Comp` instead of `Plus` and `Times`, so they don't conflict with the built-in rules for `Plus` and `Times`.

Answer (score 7):

[scala](/questions/tagged/scala)

## tl;dr

[This is legal, runnable Scala code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/Isd0krQpQvCd2wiTwIVRKA):

```scala
import language.postfixOps

object Foo:
  def +(other: this.type) = "binary infix"
  def +                   = "unary postfix"
  def unary_+             = "unary prefix"

Foo + Foo //=> "binary infix"

Foo +     //=> "unary postfix"

+ Foo     //=> "unary prefix"
```

Scala allows calling arbitrary methods with one argument using infix syntax and allows arbitrary operator characters in method names, therefore allowing arbitrary operators to be defined. Associativity and precedence, however, cannot be freely defined, they are based on the method name.

## Scala 2 (Legacy)

[Scala](https://scala-lang.org/) *mostly* doesn't deal with operators at all. [There are three rules for method calls](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#infix-operations) which allow Scala to support what "feels like" operators and operator overloading without actually having to deal with special support for operators and operator overloading:

1. The `.` for method calls can be replaced by whitespace.
2. When using the method calling syntax from #1, parentheses for a single argument list with a single argument are optional.
3. A method whose name ends with `:` is right-associative.

So, rule #1 means that I can replace

```scala
foo.bar(baz)
```

with

```scala
foo bar(baz)
```

and rule #2 means I can replace *that* with

```scala
foo bar baz
```

There is nothing special about `bar`. *Any* method call expression with a single argument list with a single argument can be written this way.

Consequently, there is nothing special about

```scala
a + b
```

It is simply the same as

```scala
a.+(b)
```

applying rules #1 and #2 from above. `+` is just a legal name for a method like any other. Scala's rules for identifiers are roughly the same as for other popular languages (alphanumeric, can't start with a number, etc.), *except* that identifiers can also contain (and be completely composed of) *operator characters*. When mixing operators and alphanumerics, they need to be separated by an underscore. So, `foo` is legal `++--::::--++!!!****` is legal, `foo_+` is legal.

The third rule means that

```scala
a +: b
```

is actually equivalent to

```scala
b.+:(a)
```

or, more precisely (observing left-to-right evaluation):

```scala
{ val __unspeakable_name__ = a; b.+:(__unspeakable_name__) }
```

This is primarily used to support the standard `::` operator for *prepending* an element to a `CONS` list. Naturally, in a single-dispatch OO language, that must be a method of the *list* object, but we still want to write the elements in the order they appear in the list:

```scala
val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
// is equivalent to
val list = Nil.::(3).::(2).::(1)
```

But what about precedence? And what about unary prefix operators? Okay, that's where my qualification from above comes in, where I wrote Scala "mostly" doesn't deal with operators.

For precedence, the rule is that the precedence is determined by the *first character* of the operator. I.e. all operators starting with `+` have the same precedence, all starting with `-` have the same precedence, and so on. The relative precedence between the starting characters is roughly the "standard" precedence from languages like C or Java, but with some modifications.

For unary prefix operators, Scala does not allow defining new ones. It only allows `+`, `-`, `~`, and `!`. Unary prefix operator expressions are translated into method calls by prefixing `unary_` to them, e.g.

```scala
+foo
-foo
~foo
!foo
```

is equivalent to

```scala
foo.unary_+
foo.unary_-
foo.unary_~
foo.unary_!
```

Note how the rule that identifiers mixing alphanumeric and operator characters must be separated by an underscore is observed, so these are legal identifiers and can be defined using normal method definition syntax.

Unary postfix operators used to be allowed by simply observing rule #1 from above:

```ruby
foo bar
```

is equivalent to

```ruby
foo.bar
```

They are not *technically* deprecated (yet!) but their use is heavily discouraged. In current versions of Scala, they require an explicit `import` (or compiler flag), and will generate a compiler warning even if explicitly enabled.

There are a couple of other rules in order to support common use cases for operator overloading:

- Function application syntax: if there is no method named `foo` in scope, then `foo(bar)` translates to `foo.apply(bar)`. This is used extensively for Factory methods, e.g. Scala has no literal syntax for collections, instead, all collections have companion objects with an `apply` method, which allows you to construct e.g. a `List` with `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`. This is also used for array and map indexing, treating arrays as functions of their indices and maps as functions of their keys (in fact, arrays and maps literally inherit from `Function`).
- Update syntax: `foo(bar) = baz` translates to `foo.update(bar, baz)`. Not used extensively, as the Scala community eschews mutability.
- Property syntax: If there is no mutable field (`var`) named `bar`, then `foo.bar = baz` translates to `foo.bar_=(baz)`.
- Assignment operators: `+=`, `-=`, etc. are just normal method names, so they can be implemented, i.e. `a += b` translates to `a.+=(b)`. However, if there is no method named `+=` but the expression `a = a + b` type checks, then that translation is chosen. This means `+=` can be overloaded, but `var n = 0; n += 1` still works as expected even though `Int` doesn't define `+=`.

There are some other "magic methods", but they are not related to operators, specifically:

- `for` comprehensions de-sugar into calls to `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter`.
- Pattern Matching de-sugars into calls to `unapply` and `unapplySeq`.

An interesting tidbit is that infix notation is also valid for *type constructors*. Application of a binary type constructor `C[A, B]` can be written as `A C B`. This is rarely used but can be useful in the context of type-level programming. For example, the type-constructor `=:=[A, B]` compiles IFF `A` and `B` are equal, and it should be obvious why being able to write it as `A =:= B` is desirable.

## Scala 3 (Current)

[Some of the rules above have been tightened up in Scala 3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/operators.html):

- It is always possible to call a method using infix syntax by enclosing it in backticks, i.e. `` foo `bar` baz `` and `` foo `+` baz `` are always allowed and are equivalent to `foo.bar(baz)` and `foo.+(baz)`.
- It is still always possible to call a method whose name consists exclusively of operator characters using infix notation, i.e. `a + b` is still allowed.
- Methods whose name contains alphanumeric characters can only be called using infix notation if they are explicitly marked `infix` at the definition site: `infix def foo(bar: SomeParameterType): SomeResultType`. Operator methods don't need an `infix` modifier.
- For operator methods, it is *encouraged* to use the `@targetName` annotation which allows you to choose a human-readable name for the method in the actual compiled code. This is especially useful if the name is illegal in the underlying target platform (e.g. the JVM). For example, `@targetName("prepend") def ++:(other: SomeParameterType): SomeResultType` will be compiled into a Java method named `prepend` whereas without the annotation it would be something like `$plus$plus$colon`, which would be the name you need to use if you want to call this method from Java, Kotlin, Ruby, or any other JVM language.

But the fundamental idea of trying to, as much as possible, treat operators as methods like any other, just with funky names, remains.

---

Disclosure: this answer was copy&pasted to https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2768/854

Answer (score 6):

## The Operator Is An Argument

In D, a few special method names are reserved for operator overloading, including `opUnary` and `opBinary`, and they are used as templates to which the operator is passed as argument.
https://dlang.org/spec/operatoroverloading.html

This means that, for example, `+x` is interpreted as `x.opUnary!"+"`, and `x + y` as `x.opBinary!"+"(y)`.
This has the major advantage that multiple syntactically related operators can be implemented by a single function template.

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    S opBinary(string Op)(in S o) const
    {
        mixin("return S(x", Op, " o.x);");
    }
    
    unittest
    {
        const x = S(21);
        const y = S(2);
        const z = x * y;
        assert(z.x == 42);
    }
}
```

Another example is that of the cast operator, implemented as `opCast` where the *type* is passed as argument.
Combined with CTFE and user-defined overload resolution, it acts similarly to the previous example.

```
struct S
{
    int x;

    T opCast(T)() const
      if(is(int : T))
    {
        return x;
    }
    T opCast(T: string)() const
    {
        return imported!"std.conv".to!string(x);
    }

    unittest
    {
        const s = S(42);
        const x = cast(long) s;
        const str = cast(string) s;
        assert(x == 42);
        assert(str == "42");
    }
}
```

## `x++` calls `++x`

> What would be a good alternative syntax for operator overloading that could [...] distinguish ++x from x++ without hacks such as unused parameters?

`x++` really means (in GNU C's syntax) `({ __auto_type _tmp = x; ++x; _tmp; })`.
This is also how both prefix and postfix (inc|dec)rementation operator in D resolve to `opUnary`.
Naturally, any copy and related semantics can be optimised away via copy elision.

Answer (score 5):

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)

In [Ruby](https://ruby-lang.org/), binary infix operators are just [syntactic sugar](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for [message sends](https://wiki.c2.com/?MessagePassing), i.e. for all binary infix operators `ω`,

```ruby
a ω b
```

is syntactic sugar for

```ruby
a.ω(b)
```

Consequently, since operator expressions are just message sends, they invoke methods just like any other message send and just like any other message send, the name of the method being invoked is the same as the message.

So, [defining an operator is just defining a method with the same name as the operator](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names). Defining a method named `plus` looks like this:

```ruby
module SomeModule
  def plus(other)
    # do something with `self` and `other`
  end
end
```

And thus, defining a method named `+` looks exactly identical:

```ruby
module SomeModule
  def +(other)
    # do something with `self` and `other`
  end
end
```

There are, however, some special cases.

Firstly, not all operators can be defined. `.` (message sending), `=` (assignment), `&&` (logical-AND), `||` (logical-OR), `and`, `or`, unary prefix `&` (unroll an object responding to `to_proc` into a block), and unary prefix `defined?` don't translate into message sends and thus cannot be defined. Unary prefix `not` cannot be defined on its own, but it translates into a message send of `!`, which means it is always identical to unary prefix `!` which *can* be defined.

Second, this scheme obviously only works for binary infix operators. Ruby does not have unary postfix operators, but it does have some unary prefix operators. The ones which can be defined are: `+`, `-`, `!`, and `~`.

Since there is no binary infix operator named `!` or `~`, these are just syntactic sugar for argument-less message sends with the same name as the operator and thus are defined with the same name, similar to binary infix operators:

```ruby
not a # is same as
!a    # is same as
a.!
# is defined using
module SomeModule
  def !
    # do something with `self`
  end
end

~a # is same as
a.~
# is defined using
module SomeModule
  def ~
    # do something with `self`
  end
end
```

In Ruby, there can be only one method with a particular name in a particular module, so it is not possible to define unary prefix `+` and `-` as a parameterless method named `+` or `-` since that would clash with the binary infix versions. So, for these two operators, the rule is slightly modified in that they are translated to `+@` and `-@`, respectively:

```ruby
+a # is same as
a.+@
# is defined using
module SomeModule
  def +@
    # do something with `self`
  end
end

-a # is same as
a.-@
# is defined using
module SomeModule
  def -@
    # do something with `self`
  end
end
```

So, long answer short: the way to disambiguate operators with the same name but different arity is to give them different names when defining them.

Answer (score 4):

In Python the methods become special only because of its name.

For example for `+`:

```python
def __add__(...):
    ...
```

Python like methods names:

- `+` -- `__add__`
- `-` -- `__sub__`
- `*` -- `__mul__`
- `/` -- `__div__`
- ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a thing called [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) in C#. You could add a `NewMethod` into an `ExistingClass` using this:

```
public static ReturnType NewMethod(this ExistingClass ParamName,...) {
    ...
}
```

It also has to be in a static class, which is only because they don't want functions outside classes in C#, unimportant to the discussion.

If we are borrowing this `this` grammar, we could come up with some straightforward ideas. In the class the operator is used upon, we could use:

```
class Type{
    ReturnType operator++(){
        //postfix ++
    }
    static ReturnType operator++(Type x){
        //prefix ++
        //May not be best.
        //It has ambiguity without the C# assumption that every function has a "this".
    }
    static ReturnType operator++(this, Type x){
        //prefix ++
        //Alternative, denoting "this" is empty.
    }
}
```

Outside a class, we could use:

```
ReturnType operator++(this Type x){
    //postfix ++
}
ReturnType operator++(Type x){
    //prefix ++
}
```

It's like we are using the prefix `++` like a standalone function and the postfix `++` like a method, imitating the order of the object and the operator in the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [attribute](https://github.com/tyr-lang/stdlib/blob/master/lang/src/operator/properties.tyr) system to define a prefix or postfix attribute. Distinction from binary operators should and commonly happens over the type system simply by checking the operand count.

The very definition can reuse the syntax of functions replacing the identifier token with an operator token ([example](https://github.com/tyr-lang/stdlib/blob/923229873df2e8a6373ac22e8940fe5301b9fed3/lang/src/integer.tyr#L20)).